# How to divide Notebook tab into two sections in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 notebooks or in other words tabs, I'll call them tabs in this question. One called `Main`, which is my primarily focus on. For this tab, I need to separate two sides to that specific tab and call them: `left_side` & `right_side`. Reason for this is, so I am able to structure the layout for that tab using `Pack` instead of `Grid`.

Here is the code for notebook for one of my Classes:

```
 class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)

        notebook.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")
        #Frames
        main = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        manual = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(main, text='Main')
        notebook.add(manual, text='Sub')
```

How can I possibly divide the `Main` tab with two sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way you do it anywhere else in tkinter. Tabs don't require anything special.

```
left = ttk.Frame(main)
right = ttk.Frame(main)

left.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
right.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Of course, you don't have to use `pack`. You can use `grid`, a `panedwindow`, etc.

Comment: what does fill and expand do Bryan? Because I'll be needing to align my content to left, because all check boxes are centered.

Comment: @HecticPython: `fill` and `expand` are documented in many places. The canonical documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26